# JTable resizing - setAutoResizeMode not working with setPreferedWidth

Tags: java, swing, jtable, width

I was given task to show users how different ResizeMode works in JTable.
So user select resize mode ,than I set this resize mode on table and then in SwingWorker I resize every few ms this table to show user how resize mode he picked would work. However when I use .setPreferedWidth() on column of table it still behaves like JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS. It does not apply rules I set before.
When I use setWidth() then table is just flickering.

```
private class SizeChanger extends SwingWorker<Object, Integer>{

    private int tempWidth;
    private boolean down;

    public SizeChanger(int tempWidth,boolean down){
        this.tempWidth=tempWidth;
        this.down=down;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {


        if (!down){

            for (int i = tempWidth; i > tempWidth/10; i--) {
                publish(i);
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } 

        } else {

            for (int i = tempWidth; i < tempWidth*10; i++) {
                publish(i);
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } 
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> size){
        for (Integer thsisize : size) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(thsisize);
        }

    }

}
```

Problem is when I call for example:

```
 table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
```

then I execute SizeChanger and table is changing size of every column ,not only last and first. So table is still behaving like JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS would be set.

```
executor.execute(new SizeChanger(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(),false));
```

When I call:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(thsisize);
```

I can see correct change only if I click on table header to change size,othervise size is not changing

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating/delayed tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 2) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson cough ... sleeping here happens on the worker thread ... OP: nevertheless your code is incorrect: you *must not* access any swing property off the EDT (as you do when grabbing the column width in doInBackground). Plus: a) 20 ms are quite short b) what's that boolean in publish? Doesn't look like you use is at all, and not overriding super (it's final anyway).

Comment: @kleopatra yes that is true ,so I remade constructor of SwingWorker. Anyway problem still occurs.

Comment: your change is even worse - now you even **change** a property off the EDT. Please read the api doc and/or the tutorial chapter of SwingWorker to learn how-to use it

Comment: @kleopatra As far as I know when I change size of column in publish method ,then it should be thread-safe.

Comment: _Problem is when I call ..._ no, your problem is that you violate Swing's threading rule - which can have all kinds of weird effects.

Comment: NOOOOO - READ THE API DOC, **NOW** (hint: publish is **not** the method to implement, you can't, actually)

Comment: @kleopatra yes you have very true. I forgot ,that this method is process(<List> chunks) , ow thanks for pointing me in right direction. However problem with resizing is still there. .setPreferredWidth(thsisize) does not accept AutoResizeMode that was set before

Answer (score 0):

Change it for `setWidth()`

```
for (Integer thsisize : size) {
   table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(thsisize);
 }
```

For what I understood, you want to change Table Column width with a Smooth effect, is that correct?

The following code worked for me:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 850; i += 5) {
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    t.start();
```

Comment: So I tried it and found out that it is showing change only when user click on table header for resizing columns during execution of SwingWorker. Also tried calling repaint and revalidate on table and scroll pane ,but it had no effect.

Comment: table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(i); must be wrapped into invokeLater, otherwise this answer is wrong